# MIPS: Code Scheduling To remove Stalls

Tags: mips

I have the following MIPS code:

```
addi $s1, $0, 10
lw   $t0, 4($s0)
srl  $t1, $t0, 1     [STALL becausee $t0 depends on lw's $t0]
add  $t2, $t1, $s1   [STALL because $t1 depends on srl's $t1]
sw   $t2, 4($s0)
```

How can I rearrange it to avoid any stalls. I see that all the 2 to 5 line's sequence can't change. We can only move the first line in between srl and add OR lw and srl. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 read after write (RAW) dependencies in your code: `addi->add`, `lw->srl`, `srl->add`, `add->sw`. These can't be fixed as you pointed out.

What you *can* do is move the `addi` instruction. I would think the best place to move this instruction would be after the `lw` because in the MIPS architecture all load instructions use a [load delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot#Load_delay_slot). This means that the instruction immediately after the load does not have access to the contents of the load. If you are using this code in a simulator such as `spim` or `MARS` this may not be simulated, but assuming you mean to use the loaded value of `$t0` in the `srl` instruction, your assembly above is actually incorrect. For this to work, there should be a `nop` in between the `lw` and `srl`.

For that reason, it would be best to move the `addi` in between the `lw` and `srl` so as to utilize the `lw` load delay slot.